# C++ Deferred Logging (Without C++11)

Tags: c++, logging, c++03

Currently, our code base has a lot of code that looks like the following:

```
void log(int level, const char *msg) {
    // logLevel is some global int defining which messages to log
    if (level <= logLevel) {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
}

...

int someNum = 3;
if (1 <= logLevel) {
    char msg[200];
    sprintf(msg, "Some format %d", someNum);
    log(1, msg);
}
```

We are using Visual Studio 2008, and therefore cannot use any features of C++11.  Is there a clean way to pass a closure to the log method, so I can remove the duplicate "if" condition?  For example, I am looking for code equivalent to the following in pre C++11 syntax:

```
void log(int level, std::function<std::string ()> getMessage) {
    if (level <= logLevel) {
        cout << getMessage() << endl;
    }
}

...

int someNum = 3;
log(1, [someNum]() -> std::string {
    std::ostringstream sstream;
    sstream << "Some format " << someNum;
    return sstream.str();
});
```

The best I could come up with is:

```
struct LogMessage {
    virtual std::string operator()() const = 0;
};

void log(int level, const LogMessage &getMessage) {
    if (level <= logLevel) {
        cout << getMessage() << endl;
    }
}

...

struct X : public LogMessage {
    X(int num) : myNum(num) { }
    std::string operator()() const {
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << "Some format " << myNum;
        return out.str();
    }
    private: const int myNum;
} a(someNum);
log(1, a);
```

Comment: You want to avoid having if condition be tested twice (by caller and log function)?

Comment: As local struct cannot be used in template (in c++03), I would say it is the best you can have.

Comment: @jpo38 Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @JeffG: Then macros could help you there. They are often used to setup trace systems.

Comment: Wouldn't the instruction cache miss caused by passing a function to a function and then executing the passed function inside be worse than a simple second integer comparison?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The question wasn't intended to be about improving efficiency.  The issue I want to address is code maintainability.  If a coworker wants to change the log level of a statement in the current code, (s)he has to change it in two places (in the guarding "if" and the call to "log").  I like the idea of only building the log message when necessary, but don't like the duplicate hard-coded constants that result.  I could create a variable prior to the conditional to store the log level, but that makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if macros are commonly not recommended, they could help in this specific case, specially if all your text can be handled by streams.

Make your log function be a macro:

```
#define LOG(level, msg) { if (level <= logLevel) { cout << msg << endl; } }
```

Then, if you do:

```
LOG( 1, "Some format " << someNum )
```

`if` test is done and only one and any complex formatting done in macro's second parameter will only be executed if log level condition is `true`.

Note: For existing lines using sprintf, you will still need to declare a function...:

```
inline std::string printNum( int someNum )
{
    char msg[200];
    sprintf(msg, "Some format %d", someNum);
    return msg;
}

LOG( 1, printNum(3) )
```

Comment: And if your macro parameter includes commas (like his example of sprintf) you can always surround the macro parameter with parenthesis so that it is passed verbatim.  You say the if won't be done twice but your example has no if.  Could you make your example be the one used in the question?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I beleve any `sprint` statement can be replaced by a stream manipulation. By the way, there is definitely a `if` with in the macro (`if (level <= logLevel)`).

Comment: Interesting idea.  Many of the offending lines are already sprintf style, while others combine both sprintf and cout.  I *could* convert everything to use the cout style, but that would require a significant amount of work, with nonzero risk of introducing an error during the conversion (there are thousands of log statements in our current codebase).  I think I prefer leaving the code as-is instead of doing all the work required to go the macro route.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer provided by @jpo38, simply add another macro to accept variadic arguments in order to support a `printf`-style function:

```
#define LOGF(LEVEL, ...)\
    if ((LEVEL) <= logLevel) {\
        char msg[200];\
        sprintf(msg, __VA_ARGS__);\
        log((LEVEL), msg);\
    }
```

Then either of the following calls would produce the same output:

```
LOG(1, "Some format " << someNum);
LOGF(1, "Some format %d", someNum);
```